# Having trouble writing a regex that works with URL's

Tags: php, html, regex

I am having trouble writing a valid regex that will validate the following:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/
example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
111.111.111.111
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.123
http://1.1.1.1
http://1.1.1.1/
example.com
example.com/
http://www.example.com/
```

I have currently only got this regex:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$|https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)|(www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)|^(?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$|(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/[\/])([^\/]+)|^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$[\/]
```

& that only validates this much: [Screenshot of Validated Domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvujJ.png)

My question is can anyone help me get a working regex that will allow all of those example domains to be allowed in a html pattern ? Thanks!

Comment: Well, given just the requirements you posted I'd say that this regular expression will work: `^.+$`... So the question is: what _other_ requirements do you have that you did _not_ post? So what should _not_ get accepted?

Comment: I just need a regex that will only work for those. Everything else that isn't listed in that example should not be able to work. Could you please also provide a full regex off what I posted to explain more what you mean about the "^.+$" because I don't understand sadly :/

Comment: That regex `^.+$` I posted was just meant as a cynical minimal suggestion to show what I meant with my question. you are not meant to use it. It is simply a trivial expression that accepts _everything_ non empty. Just ignore it.

Comment: Well you can of course see I am very new to this, so I apologies. If you have some experince, would be be willing to maybe give a shot at writing a regex that will work ?

Comment: Sure. I actually did. Take a look below.

Comment: The examples are somewhat irregular, making a regex longer: "http" and <domain>.<tld> may end with a `/` while https & (unadorned)IPv4 numerical may not.

Answer (score 2):

What about this simplified approach:

```
^(https?://)?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/?$|^(https?://)?([a-z0-9-][a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z][a-z]+/?
```

Take a look at the test bed: https://regex101.com/r/3VpAxI/1

There are however a few general issue with matching URLs by regular expressions:

- some of the strings you listed (and that are accepted) are not valid URLs.
- it is *very* hard to be picky about whether a valid TLD is specified or not.
- it is not possible to test for the specific requirements certain TLDs define.
- the given pattern does *not* accept IDN URLs.
- it currently only accepts `http(s)` URLs, no other protocol.
- it currently does *not* accept IPV6 addresses.

And it certainly might be that some strings are accepted that you do *not* want to, but actually your exclusion definition is pretty vague...

Comment: @LukeHela That is because you are using `/` as a delimiter char which is not exactly a clever thing to do when matching paths like strings. Chose another delimiter.

Comment: @SoniVimal You obviously have to turn on multi line matching and you did _not_ change the delimiter character. Did you take a look at the link I posted?

Comment: @SoniVimal _And_ you made a mistake when modifying my expression. Take a look here: http://regexr.com/3erk7

Comment: hey arkascha, i didnt downvote your answer. i am still looking for solution.

Comment: @SoniVimal I did not say so ;-)

Comment: I can confirm what @arkascha has posted so far works on my end. Works perfectly & is exactly what I needed. Still testing but I think it will work awesome, thanks for your help man!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. I am not using your url verification regex pattern. But it works. For a valid url list given by you in your question. But below regex for work with the above listed urls or like this if you change pattern it will not. here it is,

```
((http|https)\:\/\/)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.)([0-9]{1,3}\.)([0-9]{1,3}\.)([0-9]{1,3})\/?)|((http|https)\:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9-]+\.)([a-z0-9-]+\.)?([a-z]+)\/?)
```

Here I have tested it. 
https://regex101.com/r/P1ba2V/2

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This accepts a lot of strings that most likely are _not_ desired to be accepted. Examples: `11.11`, `11.com`, `foo.bar.`, `foo.bar.bazzzzzzzz`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated. Sorry for my foolish behavior. And `11.com` can be a valid url as domain can contain number and a to z character and `-`. Maybe I am wrong please correct me

Comment: Ok, now it is more or less identical with the solution I came up with. You still want to make sure that TLDs need to have at least two characters, though.